# chaining calls to static methods

Tags: c++, static

In C++, it is easy to chain method calls if each method returns a reference to `*this`. But what if the methods are static - how can I define static methods that will allow the following chain:

```
MyClass::setA(a)::setB(b)::setC(c) ...
```

instead of:

```
MyClass::setA(a);
MyClass::setB(b);
MyClass::setC(C);
...
```

? What exactly should each static method return?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to chain. Since methods are static, their return value would be moot, wouldn't it? So you can just call those methods one by one.

Comment: @SergeyA I want  to avoid having to write "MyClass::" in front of each method. See my edit

Comment: I don't think there is anything that you could return that would allow this syntax. Anyway, static methods should be so rare that this shouldn't be needed in practice.

Comment: `auto setA = [](int x){ MyClass::setA(x); };` then `setA(7);`  Repeat for the other two.

Comment: @Eljay the whole point of defining a static method is to put the method in the namespace of the class, rather than in the global namespace..

Comment: Oh, I thought the whole point was to avoid having to write "MyClass::" in front of each one.